# Cannot interpret token '!' at position 5

Tags: c#

I have a column named 'Jul' which contains some values like '123' and '-'. I'm trying to get sum of column by adding values and neglecting '-'. I tried:

```
object julysum;
julysum = Convert.ToDouble(FormattedPurchaseSummaryTable.Compute("SUM(Jul)", "Jul != '-'"));
```

but i'm getting error: `Cannot interpret token '!' at position 5.`
How can i resolve this error?

Comment: Try `julysum = Convert.ToDouble(FormattedPurchaseSummaryTable.Compute("SUM(Jul)", "Jul <> '-'"));`. The `!=` is C# inequality operator, you need to use `<>`.

Comment: Hi @TetsuyaYamamoto, what does `<>` mean? I replaced `!=` with `<>` but now i'm getting:  `Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.`

Answer (score 3):

There is no `!=` operator.

You likely want `<>`.

Please read here for more information on what operators are available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#operators

Comment: Hi @Blam, I replaced `!=` with `<>` and now i'm getting this:  `Invalid usage of aggregate function Sum() and Type: String.`

Answer (score 1):

[Blam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640397/15498) already pointed you towards the expression language. Having fixed the first issue, we need to fix the second which is that `Jul` is a string, not an integer (or float, etc). So we need to convert it as well.

**But**, per [`Compute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) I don't think it'll support a complex expression within the `SUM` to do the `CONVERT`.

So I think what you need to do is to add a new `DataColumn` with an expression something like:

```
IIF(Jul != '-',CONVERT(Jul,'System.Int32'),0)
```

And then compute your `SUM` over this new column instead.

Comment: Indeed! From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2#aggregates there's the statement: *An aggregate can only be applied to a single column and no other expressions can be used inside the aggregate.* so a new column will be required in order to use the result inside an aggregate

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, is it necessary to add another `DataColumn`? Is there any other way?

Comment: @AdityaPradhan - I supplied one link, Rob's supplied another, both saying that you're only allowed a plain column name inside an aggregate function. You could of course just force `Jul` to be an `int` from the outset, but then you'd just need to deal with the `-`s earlier whilst populating your table since an `int` cannot contain something that isn't a number.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i got your point and tried to add another temporary column but i got the same error again.